# is 'Have a Questions?' a correct English

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns

I know this sounds silly but I purchased a template for my website and on the footer and contact page it has the `<h2 class="">Have a Questions?</h2>` text. Is the English correct or should I go on to edit. (to `Have a Question` )?

Comment: I hope you did not pay a lot for the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not correct English, as **a** is a defined article for *singular* nouns. Therefore, you should go ahead and change it to

> Have a question?

as you suggested yourself.

Comment: Alright Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer helped you, please accept it by clicking on the check symbol next to it. :)

Comment: Do you have a question? is more contemporary.